# How can I navigate to Lombok generated implementations

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I'm wondering if it would be possible to navigate directly to the methods generated by Lombok using Intellij IDEA.

For instance, for this given example:

```
@Builder
public class AClass {

  private String body;

}
```

trying to go to the implementation of `AClass#builder` in an instruction like `AClass.builder().build()` results in Intellij navigating to `AClass`, instead of taking me to the real compiled method, which is generated under `target` directory

Answer (score 1):

Please feel free to create an issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA
Currently you can't change the behavior.

Comment: for those interested, I created the issue some time ago: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-294797